# What is the maximum number of knights we can put on a chessboard such that no knights of different colors attack each other?

Tags: linear-programming, discrete-optimization, chessboard

Let's suppose we have three different colors of knights: red, yellow, and green.

What is the maximum number of knights that we can put on a chessboard, such that no knights of different colors attack each other, and there are equal numbers of all three colors (e.g., four red, four yellow, and four green knights)?

Design a linear program that will solve this problem.

**My Attempt**

I am trying this on a small 3x3 board first and will try to generalize later. So far, this is the objective function and constraints that I have.
[image]

I explained why I added each constraint in the picture. However, I am not sure if this is the right approach since it seems over complicated. Could I get some verification if I am going in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: The board is too small at $3\times 3.$ Neighbor graph is just a loop of length $8$ and a single unreachable vertex. We can do two knights of each color on that graph. Better to start with $4\times 4.$

Comment: Looking at my drawing, it seems I have made a mistake and you're right that there can only be two of each color. Do you think the constraints I have will be able to accomplish this task if I were to generalize them for larger boards?

Comment: As I said, $3\times 3$ is easy compared to the other cases, because the adjacency graph is simple for the $3$ case.

Comment: Put a white knight on every square. That's the absolute best solution. (OK, the other solution, put a black knight on every square).

Comment: We can't only put one color because we need to have equal numbers of each color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better choice of decision variables (which will naturally lead to a linear formulation) is to let binary decision variable $x_{ijc}$ indicate whether square $(i,j)$ contains a knight of color $c$ and let nonnegative integer variable $k$ denote the number of knights of each color. The problem is to maximize $\sum_{i,j,c} x_{ijc}$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_c x_{ijc} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $(i,j)$} \\
\sum_{i,j} x_{ijc} &= k &&\text{for all $c$} \\
x_{i_1j_1c_1} + x_{i_2j_2c_2} &\le 1 &&\text{for $(i_1,j_1,c_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2,c_2)$ with $|(i_1-i_2)(j_1-j_2)|=2$ and $c_1 < c_2$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. That last constraint is genius. I wouldn't have thought of $|(i_1-i_2)(j_1-j_2)|=2$ to make sure that no two colors attack each other. I would have listed out each space with $i\pm 2$ and $j\pm1$ or vice versa. guess I overthought it.

Comment: Glad to help.  Yes, that is just a compact way to express it.  Please mark my answer as accepted.